# Tmux: change border's color of previews when choosing sessions

Tags: tmux

When I create several sessions and use `prefix + s` to change between them, the lower half of the screen shows a preview of each window, with its index and name. How can I change the border's color of panes showing?

Picture:

[image: screenshot of session chooser]

Comment: How are you switching sessions?  Do you mean `prefix + s` (ie. `Ctrl+b` then `s`): "Select a new session for the attached client interactively" rather than `Ctrl+s`, which usually locks up the terminal, but is bound to "Search forward" when in emacs-style copy-mode?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `prefix+s`. Then we see a list of session and one or more panes in a window..etc but they have border to distnguish other, I need a way to change the border's color of them.

Comment: OK, but I don't know which border you're referring to.  Where is this "half horizontal screen"?  The session list appears at the top of the current pane (one highlighted in orange, the rest in white-on-black), and the usual status line (green) is at the bottom.  This might be a situation where a screenshot would help.

Comment: Thanks, I've just added a picture for more clarification.

Comment: Ah.  Which version of `tmux` is this?  That seems to be a newer feature (2.6 + )?

Answer (score 1):

Those previews aren't actually "panes", in tmux terminology, even though they share the terminal area in a similar manner.  So (in current `tmux`, 2.7), they have no config setting of their own, and will be shown using `active-window-style`.  If you think this is an oversight, you could raise a [feature request](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ#user-content-why-doesnt-tmux-do-x):

> ## Why doesn't tmux do $x?
>
> Please send feature requests by email to tmux-users@googlegroups.com.

## Patch and recompile

Alternatively, if you're comfortable building `tmux` from source, it's easy enough to modify the functions responsible.

The vertical lines between the previews are drawn by `screen_write_vline`, and the box around all of them by `screen_write_box`.  Both functions can be found in [`screen-write.c`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/31508228bc26306a7fbf138c9df2e7210e9e5a37/screen-write.c#L485), and contain this line:

```
    memcpy(&gc, &grid_default_cell, sizeof gc);
```

`gc` is of type `struct grid_cell`, which includes members `fg` and `bg` for foreground and background respectively.

`grid_default_cell` is a `const`, defined in [`grid.c`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/31508228bc26306a7fbf138c9df2e7210e9e5a37/grid.c#L39).  Both `fg` and `bg` are 8, meaning `default`: it will use the same values as `window-active-style`, or (if that wasn't set) the terminal's own defaults.

To override this, you could change `gc` immediately afterwards:

```
    memcpy(&gc, &grid_default_cell, sizeof gc);
    gc.fg = 1;
```

This would set the foreground to red before drawing the line in question.

### Colour to int conversion

In config files, `tmux` recognizes colours in the following formats:

> The colour is one of: black, red, green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan, white, aixterm bright
>       variants (if supported: brightred, brightgreen, and so on), colour0 to colour255 from the
>       256-colour set, default, or a hexadecimal RGB string such as ‘#ffffff’.

When setting them in the source, you'll have to provide them as an `int`.  From reading the function [`colour_fromstring` in `colour.c`](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/31508228bc26306a7fbf138c9df2e7210e9e5a37/colour.c#L166), you can find their numerical representations:

- Basic colours: 0-7
- default: 8
- "bright" versions of basic colours: 90-97
- index from the [256color palette](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Xterm_256color_chart.svg):  `COLOUR_FLAG_256 |`*index*
- True Color (24-bit RGB): `COLOUR_FLAG_RGB | 0x`*RRGGBB*

Comment: Thanks, but the same `tmux.conf` that I use on archlinux machine and on `bash.exe` - ubuntu on wsl on windows10 that is `xterm` terminal fallbacks `black` color and I don't see the `borders` in case of `wsl`. I did use terminal through `bash.exe` and it's xterm, ssh from ubuntu/wsl to a archlinux vm on windows10 host that share the same all configs. I have `window-active-style` set in `tmux.conf` to `fg=color250,bg=black`

Comment: That's a lot of information I can't really parse.  You should update your OP to include `tmux.conf`, all relevant version numbers, and make it clear what results you get in each environment (native Arch, native WSL, `ssh` from WSL to Arch).  You should also try with one of the basic 16 colours in case WSL's terminal can't handle more.  If your actual question was "why don't these lines appear on WSL when they do on Linux?", that could probably have been answered without diving into the source code.